# Divergence theorem for objects defined by parts

Tags: manifolds, vector-analysis, divergence-theorem

I'm asked to calculate the flux through a manifold defined by: $$\begin{align}M = &\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert\:z = 4-3\,x^2-3\,y^2,\:z\in[1,4]\}\\\\&\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert\:x^2+y^2=1,\: z\in[0,1]\} \\\\&\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert\:x^2+y^2\leq1,\:z =0\}\end{align}$$ In other words, this surface:
[image]

Through a Vector-field F = $\left(\begin{array}{c}x\,y\\ -\dfrac{y^2}{2}\\ z\end{array}\right)$

Now what I ask myself: can I use Divergence Theorem in the meaning of $$\int_{\partial M}\langle F,N\rangle\,\mathrm{dS} = \int_{M_1} \text{div}\:F\,\mathrm{dV}+\int_{M_2}\text{div}\:F\,\mathrm{dV}$$

since $M$ is a closed surface but can't covered by one integral, but by 2 ($M_1:$ the paraboloid, $M_2:$ the cylinder).

I'm also having a hard time calculating the volume integral (in case I can calculate it this way) of the paraboloid: $$\int_{M_1} \text{div}\:F\,\mathrm{dV} = \int_1^4\int_0^{2\,\pi}\int_0^r \text{div}\:F\,r\,\mathrm{dr\,d\varphi\,dh} $$

Especiallay because $r$ is varying depending on $h$. My simple guess: $r(h) = h+3\,r^2$ ?

Comment: The simplest way to think about this is the region in XY-plane as $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. Now for any point $(x, y)$ in this region, $z$ is bound above by the paraboloid. So $0 \leq z \leq 4 - 3r^2$. So it is easier to integrate wrt $dz$ first as the below answer suggests. If you integrate wrt $dr$ first, you will have to split it into two integrals.

Comment: But if you extend the paraboloid to $z = 0$, it will have radius $r = \sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}}$. That's why I deprived from integrating this low. Otherwise, it also makes sense somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the divergence theorem is the right idea. You have

$$\operatorname{div}(F)=\frac{\partial(xy)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\left(-\frac{y^2}2\right)}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial(z)}{\partial z}=y-y+1=1$$

so the flux through $M$ is indeed equal to the volume of the region $R$ interior to $M$. You can capture this in rectangular coordinates by the integral,

$$\iiint_R\mathrm dV=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_0^{4-3x^2-3y^2}\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$$

or more cleanly in cylindrical coordinates by

$$\iiint_R\mathrm dV=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{4-3r^2}r\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: Seems pretty easy this way. Can I also write $\displaystyle{\int_{M^{\mathrm{o}}}}$ to adumbrate integrating the interior of M?

Comment: Sure, as long as it's clear to the reader.